# boost::make_shared<string>() vs boost::make_shared<string>(string(""))

Tags: c++, boost

Question 1> Is it true that the usage of Line 1 is better than Line 2?

```
boost::shared_ptr<string> shpStr = boost::make_shared<string>(); // Line 1
boost::shared_ptr<string> shpStr = boost::make_shared<string>(string("")); // Line 2
```

Question 2> In general, is it true that we should always use Line 1 instead of Line 2?

```
boost::shared_ptr<Object> shpStr = boost::make_shared<Object>(); // Line 1
boost::shared_ptr<Object> shpStr = boost::make_shared<Object>(Object()); // Line 2
```

where Object is a class with default constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`make_shared` will pass all of its arguments to the constructor of the object it creates. So what will happen is the following:

1. No arguments, so `make_shared` will just call something like `new string();`
2. You create a temporary `string` with argument `""`, i.e. an empty string. Let's call it `tmp`. Now `make_shared` will pass that to the newly created `string`, i.e. call something like `new string(tmp)`, i.e. in total `new string(string(""))`. So you call the `char const*` constructor of string, followed by the copy constructor, just to create an empty string. Overkill, isn't it?

Answer (score 7):

> Is it true that the usage of Line 1 is better than Line 2?

Yes. The first says what it means: make a shared, default-constructed string. The second adds some unnecessary noise (make a string from an empty string literal, then make another by copying it), and possibly unnecessary runtime overhead, to achieve the same effect.

> In general, is it true that we should always use Line 1 instead of Line 2?

Yes. There's no point creating a temporary just to copy and destroy it, rather than just creating the object you actually want.